# Parse and TryParse methods for phone numbers

Tags: c#, parsing

Let's assume I have a class `PhoneNumber` which accepts phone numbers in the format "123-456-789" (3 groups with 3 digits each, split by dashes). Now, I want to extend the class `PhoneNumber` with a static `Parse` and `TryParse` method. What is the best way to do so while keeping following requirements:

- Code reuse between `Parse` and `TryParse`
- Well-known API (see `DateTime.TryParse`)

Following code shows the first attempt of how I would implement such `Parse`/`TryParse` methods. `TryParseInternal` collects a list of exceptions/anomalies for the given codeline input string. Static method `Parse` throws an exception if anything is wrong with the given codeline while `TryParse` just returns `true`/`false` to indicate parsing success.

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    public string Part1 { get; }
    public string Part2 { get; }
    public string Part3 { get; }

    public PhoneNumber(string part1, string part2, string part3)
    {
        Part1 = part1;
        Part2 = part2;
        Part3 = part3;
    }

    // Example implementation for TryParse
    public static bool TryParse(string codeline, out PhoneNumber value)
    {
        if (!TryParseInternal(codeline, out value).Any())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Example implementation for Parse
    public static PhoneNumber Parse(string codeline)
    {
        var exceptions = TryParseInternal(codeline, out var esr);
        if (!exceptions.Any())
        {
            return esr;
        }

        throw new ParseException(exceptions);
    }

    private static List<Exception> TryParseInternal(string codeline, out PhoneNumber value)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        if (codeline == null)
        {
            exceptions.Add(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(codeline)));
        }

        else if (codeline == "")
        {
            exceptions.Add(new ArgumentException(nameof(codeline)));
        }

        var match = Regex.Match(codeline, @"^(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{3})$");
        if (match.Success == false)
        {
            exceptions.Add(new ArgumentException("Format is invalid", nameof(codeline)));
        }

        if (exceptions.Any())
        {
            value = null;
        }
        else
        {
            value = new PhoneNumber(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[3].Value);
        }

        return exceptions;
    }

    public class ParseException : AggregateException
    {
        public ParseException(string message) : base(message)
        {
        }

        public ParseException(IEnumerable<Exception> exceptions) : base(exceptions)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Following XUnit tests demonstrate failing/succeeding `Parse` and `TryParse` scenarios:

```
public class PhoneNumberTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ParseTest_Success()
    {
        // Arrange
        var codeline = "123-456-789";

        // Act
        var esr = PhoneNumber.Parse(codeline);

        // Assert
        esr.Part1.Should().Be("123");
        esr.Part2.Should().Be("456");
        esr.Part3.Should().Be("789");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ParseTest_InvalidFormat()
    {
        // Arrange
        var codeline = "X-X-X";

        // Act
        Action action = () => PhoneNumber.Parse(codeline);

        // Assert
        action.Should().Throw<PhoneNumber.ParseException>().Which.InnerExceptions[0].Message.Should().Contain("Format is invalid");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TryParseTest_Success()
    {
        // Arrange
        var codeline = "123-456-789";

        // Act
        var success = PhoneNumber.TryParse(codeline, out var esr);

        // Assert
        success.Should().BeTrue();
        esr.Part1.Should().Be("123");
        esr.Part2.Should().Be("456");
        esr.Part3.Should().Be("789");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TryParseTest_InvalidFormat()
    {
        // Arrange
        var codeline = "X-X-X";

        // Act
        var success = PhoneNumber.TryParse(codeline, out var esr);

        // Assert
        success.Should().BeFalse();
        esr.Should().BeNull();
    }
}
```

Is there anything in the given approach you would do differently? Do you see any potential problems? What about performance? Would it be better to collect strings instead of exceptions in terms of memory overhead?

Any recommendation/hint is welcome.

**Update 2019-02-01:** Thanks for the discussion so far. The focus should not lay on the phone number and the 3x3 digits I chose. This format does not even exist in my home country. It's just about **how you would implement `Parse` and `TryParse` as static methods** of a class.

**Update 2019-02-08:** I found a proper solution for this, but I guess it's not relevant anymore as some people here are more concerned about collecting rewards than finding solutions. Thanks for those who contributed.

Comment: Be careful with `\d` in your regex. `"๑๒๓-๔๕๖-๗๘๙"` will be accepted as a valid phone number. Doesn't have to be a problem, but depending on what is done next with the data, it might just be ... `[0-9]` is probably closer to what you intended.

Comment: Phone numbers aren't amenable to parsing. Your entire premise is wrong. See https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

Comment: Came here to share libphonenumber too. Parsing phone number is hard. Please avoid doing it for any serious work. Whenever you can, use libphonenumber. [official C# port](https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp)

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, phone numbers *in general* may not be amenable to parsing, but in a restricted case, they parse just fine.  For example, a United States phone number written in standard format can be parsed successfully with a one-line regex.

Comment: I vote to close this question as off-topic because OP posted code that has no purpose and thus lacks context, consequently isn't interested in a review but a discussion about the design of the two methods. OP should have asked it on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: _found a proper solution for this, but I guess it's not relevant anymore as some people here are more concerned about collecting rewards than finding solutions._ - this is not true - each community has its special rules and this one requires real and working code which you have not provided so consequently it got closed because reviewing and improving code that virtually does not exist is pointless. Would you have asked this question on Software Engineering where it perfectly fits their rules the outcome would have been quite different.

Comment: @t3chb0t does it make sense to migrate this post there?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ this is a tough one because while the question would now be on-topic there the answers wouldn't... the information provided by OP later makes it a nasty mix of various yes/no arguments. I think it would be best to leave it as is and ask a new question there.

Answer (score 11):

> ```
>     public PhoneNumber(string part1, string part2, string part3)
>     {
>         Part1 = part1;
>         Part2 = part2;
>         Part3 = part3;
>     }
> ```

I'm confused. The existence of `TryParse` tells me that there are important validity constraints on the number, but there's a public constructor which doesn't validate its arguments. It seems that I could easily make an instance of `PhoneNumber` for which `Parse(phoneNumber.ToString())` doesn't round-trip.

In fact, I'm even more confused: `PhoneNumber` doesn't override `ToString()` or any of the identity methods (`GetHashcode`, `Equals`, `operator==`, etc). Why not?

---

> ```
>     public static bool TryParse(string codeline, out PhoneNumber value)
>     {
>         if (!TryParseInternal(codeline, out value).Any())
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

IMO this is a failure to properly use the Boolean type. I would prefer

```
    public static bool TryParse(string codeline, out PhoneNumber value)
    {
        return !TryParseInternal(codeline, out value).Any();
    }
```

---

> ```
>     private static List<Exception> TryParseInternal(string codeline, out PhoneNumber value)
>     {
>         var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
>         if (codeline == null)
>         {
>             exceptions.Add(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(codeline)));
>         }
>
>         else if (codeline == "")
>         {
>             exceptions.Add(new ArgumentException(nameof(codeline)));
>         }
>
>         var match = Regex.Match(codeline, @"^(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{3})$");
> ```

This aggregation strategy lets you down (and so does your test suite) when I pass `null` for `codeline`. Instead of the `ArgumentNullException` or `ParseException` which I would expect, I get a `NullReferenceException` from `Regex.Match`.

---

Another issue I see with the aggregation strategy is that the code repeats itself a bit: `TryParseInternal` checks `exceptions.Any()` to decide how to handle the `out` parameter, and then its caller checks `esr.Any()` to decide how to handle the `out` parameter. If you are attached to the aggregation (I personally don't see the point) then this might be simpler if the inner method returned `ParseException` instead of `List<Exception>`.

---

Which prompts me to say: code to the interface, not the implementation. If a method can return `IList<T>` then that's preferable to returning `List<T>`.

Comment: Mhmm... the last statement is questionable as arrays are also of type `IList<T>`. I'd say it's better to use the interface as it gives you more options especially during testing.

Comment: @t3chb0t, I don't understand. What's the problem with using a type which arrays implement? And why do you say that the statement is questionable and then agree with it?

Comment: Oh, crappy-crap, I misread the _then that's preferable to returning_ as _then it's preferable to return_ --- sorry!!! ;-]

Comment: @Peter Array is probably the worst example to use here. Array should never have implemented `IList` in the first place, since it can't correctly implement the interface (Add doesn't make sense for a fixed-size array). Certainly a mistake on Microsoft's part, but I'd strongly advise against returning arrays when the static type says `IList`.

Comment: @Voo, if you're arguing that `IList<T>` should never be used then please be direct. If  you aren't arguing that, then this is completely off topic.

Comment: @Peter I'm arguing that your claim "code to the interface, not the implementation" is wrong for some very prominent classes of the standard library due to errors in their implementation. It's a good idea in principle but shouldn't be stated too generally without mentioning the caveats. Seemed fitting considering that t3chb0t already brought it up unintentionally.

Comment: @Voo since `IList<T>` implements the `ICollection<T>` interface and this one provides the `IsReadOnly` property it's perfectly suited for arrays too thus a list does not necessarily has to support `Add`, it's then a read-only-list/collection.

Comment: @t3chb0t Wasn't aware that property existed, interesting. But yes that technically would make it compliant. I don't think I've ever actually *seen* any code make such a check in practice though - still bad API design imo, but at least LSP compliant.

Answer (score 5):

#### Class design

Apart from the parsing logic I find the `PhoneNumber` class should not have its three `PartX` properties but a single property `Value` that stores all digits.

How many parts a phone number has it's purely a visual representation and should be implemented either by the UI or alternatively by `ToString(format)`.

#### Parsing

I wouldn't say that restricting phone numbers to exact three equally long parts is a good idea as there is no standard format for them. I sugesst to just match the digits and other allowed separators and capture only digts:

```
var digits =
    Regex
        .Matches("123-456-789", @"(?:(\d)|[-])")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => m.Groups[1].Success)
        .Select(m => m.Value);
```

Comment: Worse case if he keeps 3 parts, they should be named properly such as AreaCode, Prefix, and LineNumber.

Comment: Agree. The question however was how Parse/TryParse can be implemented in a proper and safe way. The phone number example is just fictive.